# Updating only one key value by using for loop with different different value and return the dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Here is my current dictionary:-

```
my_list_of_dict = [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'},{'A': 'a1', B: 'b1'}]
```

I have values like this:-

```
values = ['c', 'c1']
```

I tried this code:-

```
for my_dict in my_list_of_dict:
    for value in values:
       my_dict['C'] = value
```

But this code returns the output as the last value:-

```
my_dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c1'}
my_dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c1'}
```

**Expected Output is:-**

```
my_dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'}
my_dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c1'}
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Why you expect 2 dictionaries?

Comment: I would not expect any output at all from this code. What do you mean by output?

Comment: Don't name your dicts `dict`, this will cause you grief.

Comment: because I want to set only one value in the key 'C'

Comment: Dictionary in python can't have the same key multiple time so you can either choose another key to separate the two value or continue to use the same keys but put the values in list, this way you can have a key with multiple values

Comment: You can see your expected output when you print `print(my_dict)` in for loop. As a result the output will be `'C': 'c1'` , as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `range` to loop over both `my_list_of_dict` and `values`

```
my_list_of_dict = [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'},{'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1'}]
values = ['c', 'c1']

for i in range(len(my_list_of_dict)):
    my_list_of_dict[i]['C'] = values[i]

print(my_list_of_dict)
#[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'}, {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1'}]
```

Comment: @Learner great, please see my updated answer